# Changing placeholder via AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a text input field whose placeholder I want to change every few seconds. However I don't want to pollute my controller with this so I want to encapsulate this functionality into a directive.

This is what my directive looks like:

```
myApp.directive('searchBox', ['$interval', function($interval) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link(scope, element, attrs) {
            $interval(function() {
                attrs.placeholder = 'New';
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}])
```

And the html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Old" ng-model="search" search-box>
```

However the placeholder stubbornly doesn't change, even though in the console `attrs.placeholder` can be seen to change to 'Test' from 'Hello'. Any ideas?

[**PLUNKR**: https://plnkr.co/edit/Oy1M8FPTXxzB9oYMJqlx?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/Oy1M8FPTXxzB9oYMJqlx?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change attributes values via the `attr` object (it's just a static reflection of your element attributes). Instead, update your element using `element.attr('placeholder', 'Test')` or `attrs.$set('placeholder', 'Test')`.

Comment: May you and your children be blessed forevermore.

Comment: What's the difference between the two methods?

Comment: See for yourself: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/b94626cb9bc03a067feb7c6f0302f811edfd8e67/src/ng/compile.js#L1537

Basically, `attrs.$set` allows you to use interpolation in your value (e.g. `attrs.$set('placeholder', 'Test {{ myVar }}')`, and the attribute key is “normalized” à-la-Angular, meaning to update the `data-foo` attribute you'd use `dataFoo` as key.

`element.attr` is just a regular DOM attribute update.

Comment: `attrs.$set` also triggers observers (setup with `attrs.$observe`) and sanitizes values using ngSanitize

Comment: Ok, sounds like $set is the one to go for. Thanks!